# How to remove 0.1% from a list?

Tags: python, arrays, regex, list, tuples

i have following list

```
data = [    '0.1%',
 'hello',
 'how are you guys',
  '0.1%',
  '1%',
 '0.1%',
  '1%', ]
```

i tried this :

```
cell = float(data.rstrip("%"))
```

i want to remove 1% and 0.1%

expected output:

```
    data = [ 'hello','how are you guys' ]
```

Comment: So, what have you tried? This looks very easy if you know how a loop works, or how a list comprehension works. Have you gone through the tutorial on python.org?

Comment: `[x for x in data if '%' not in x]` ?

Comment: `rstrip` works only with single string, not with list of strings. Probably only in `pandas.DataFrame` you could do `dataframe.str.rstrip('%')` to remove it from all elements in table. In pure Python you have to use `for`-loop for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
new_list = [d for d in data if d not in ['0.1%', '1%']]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna use something more generic:

```
result = []
for i in data:
    try:
        float(i.strip('%'))
    except:
        result.append(i)
```

OUTPUT:

```
['hello', 'how are you guys']
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another crafty way to do this!

```
data = ['0.1%',
    'hello',
    'how are you guys',
    '0.1%',
    '1%',
    '0.1%',
    '1%', ]

unwanted = [0, 3, 4, 5, 6,]

for ele in sorted(unwanted, reverse=True):
    del data[ele]


print(data)
```